# How to install cozy fireplace?

Tags: init-file

I am a beginner. Like a complete and total noob.

I want to get this cozy fireplace thing for fun on emacs -> https://github.com/johanvts/emacs-fireplace

How do I install it? I do not understand the melpa method, but I tried the manual install... here is how far I got...

I used my Mac's terminal to transfer the fireplace.el to `~/.emacs.d/fireplace` but stopped there because I have no idea how to compile the file bc when I type `byte-compile-file` it says Byte compile file and when I type `~/.emacs.d/fireplace` it says read error...

So i moved on and thought i would figure it out later, and instead tried to figure out how to put the code: `load "~/.emacs.d/fireplace/fireplace"` in the init file. BUT ALAS! I found out that GNU emacs does not come with an init file! So I had to create one... but I do not know how, or how to put code into it... please help I am very new to this community...

(using a 2019 Macbook running macOSS Big Sur 11.2.3 if that means anything, also I am using GNU emacs)

Comment: https://melpa.org/#/getting-started Did you read the `Getting Started`? Just the `Installing` part is enough. `MELPA` is one of the easiest package managers. Otherwise I'd look to `use-package`.

Comment: I would suggest that you start emacs and go through the tutorial by pressing `C-h t` , that is `Control-h` and then `t`. You need to learn at least some conventions so that we can make sure we talk the same language. In particular, the instructions for byte compiling the file were `M-x byte-compile-file` which means "type `Meta-x`" and then type `byte-compile-file`. Usually, the `Meta` key is the key that's labeled `Alt` on your keyboard and you type `M-x` by holding the `Alt` key down while you press the `x` key.